# WPF Build ContextMenu dynamically via MVVM

Tags: wpf, menu, contextmenu, datatemplate

I have a TreeView where I display items bound via the TreeViews `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource`. The context-menu of the TreeView changes based on which item is selected. The menu-items depend on the selected item. This means: the context-menu is built completely dynamic. For this purpose I wrote a `MenuItemModel` class, that serves as the business-object for a menu item. Like this:

```
public class MenuItemModel : ViewModelBase
{
  public string Header { get; set; }
  public string Icon { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
  public UiCommand Command { get; set; }
}
```

So far so good. But now I have two questions:

**Question 1** How can I display a separator in the menu? I have another class `SeparatorMenuItemModel` that I planned to use for separators. But in that case my ContextMenu needs to contain a `Separator` and not a `MenuItem`. How can I do that?

**Question 2** I tried to use a `DataTemplate` to customize how my MenuItems are displayed. But that does not change the menu itself, just the content-part. I'd have to use a `ControlTemplate` for that, but how can I make my Menu change `ControlTemplate` the way I could do with `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way that resolved both issues.

First: I have created two styles. One for the type `MenuItemModel` and another for the type `SeparatorMenuItemModel`:

```
<Style x:Key="theMenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  ...
</Style>

<Style x:Key="theSeparatorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate> ... </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

I used the styles to also change my control template (in addition to some other stuff that's not important here).

I then used a StyleSelector that chooses the Style to be applied based on the type of the item displayed. Like this:

```
  <TreeView.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenuItemRoot.ChildItems}"
                 ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource MenuItemStyleSelector}" />
  </TreeView.ContextMenu>
```

And the StyleSelector itself is defined like this:

```
public class MenuItemStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
  public Style MenuItemStyle { get; set; }
  public Style SeparatorStyle { get; set; }

  public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
  {
    if (item is SeparatorMenuItemModel)
      return SeparatorItemStyle;
    return MenuItemStyle;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a classic Composition pattern here. As far as the SeparatorMenuItemModel, how about having both the MenuItemModel and the SeparatorMenuItemModel inherit from a common class or interface, for example IMenuItemModel (or MenuItemModelBase)? Then you could use

```
public ObservableCollection<IMenuItemModel> ChildItems {get; set;}
```

to contain both.

Not sure I entirely understand question 2, but it's important to understand that a ControlTemplate *completely* replaces the visual tree for a control; essentially you are able to (and have to) completely rebuild the control from scratch. Quite often this is a lot more work than you really want to do.

Comment: My "SeparatorMenuItemModel" derives from MenuItemModel. So that's not an issue. I was talking about how to make my Menu display either a "MenuItem" or a "Separator" based on the datatype.

For the ControlTemplate: yeah I know. I just wanted to know if there are some kind of "ControlTemplateSelector" mechanisms available.